# Panel transparency in ggplot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, transparency

I want to my output ggplot2 graphics have transparent border (panel) but white (not transparent) plot background.

I tried these two options

```
d <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(y = d, x = 1)
p <- ggplot(df) + stat_boxplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) 
# first option
p <- p + theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.major = element_blank()
)
# second option
# p <- p + theme(
#   panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), 
#   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
#   panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
#   plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA)
# )

png('plot.png', width = 300, height = 300, units = "px", bg = "transparent")
print(p)
dev.off()
```

But I got unsatisfactory output
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the trick is obvious. I have misunderstood what panel and plot background is. So this one should work:

```
# third option
 p <- p + theme(
   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
   panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
   plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but another approach is simply to choose a transparent fill.  For example, see these [transparent colors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.php#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,Hexadecimal%20Colors%20With%20Transparency,digits%20between%2000%20and%20FF.).

Applying this, you could do:

```
theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='#ff000080') )
```